# How to use Microsoft Lync 2013/SharePoint in Unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, lync-2013

I need to use Microsoft Lync 2013 in Unity 3d. I have download following DLLs of Microsoft Lync 2013:

- Microsoft.Lync.Controls
- Microsoft.Lync.Controls.Framework
- Microsoft.Lync.Model
- Microsoft.Lync.Utilities
- Microsoft.Office.Uc

After imporing these dlls in unity project i can Access Lync Client and other functions but unity gives me following errors:

```
Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/x86/Microsoft.Lync.Controls.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:

Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/x86/Microsoft.Lync.Controls.Framework.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:

Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/x86/Microsoft.Lync.Utilities.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:

MethodAccessException: Method `System.__ComObject..ctor()' is inaccessible from method `System.__ComObject..ctor()'
System.__ComObject..ctor () (at <39b6717027e94f68a4d7333ec0540cb3>:0)
(wrapper cominterop-invoke) System.__ComObject..ctor()
System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.EnsureOI () (at <abe166c977f040c8b40c4dda29b08aea>:0)
Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient (System.Boolean sideBySideLync) (at <abe166c977f040c8b40c4dda29b08aea>:0)
Test.Start () (at Assets/Test.cs:16)
```

I am using Unity 2018.3 Beta 7.Its neither working on 2018.2f1 nor 2018.2f13.
What should i do now to use these libraries ?

Unity Project Settings:

.Net Framework 4.x

Platform: Standalone Windows

Comment: make a native plugin, reference all that stuff in the native plugin.  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html

Comment: These are already C# DLLs.

Comment: They are C# DLLs that reference non C# DLLs.

Comment: You could also try 32 vs 64 bit version of unity.